# spring + tomcat - обновляется session id при каждом запросе

Tags: java, tomcat

На локальном Tomcate всё нормально работает, это же приложение на сервере, на каждый новый запрос новая сессия.
В шапке справа session id выводится - {deleted_link}. Сессию так получаю:

```
request.getSession().getId()`
```

Есть идеи какие настройки посмотреть? Я так понимаю дело в Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема cостояла в том, что в связке Apache + Tomcat неправильно указывается путь cookies, а именно /web_app_folder вместо /. Всё это безобразие происходит, когда привязываешь домен через virtualhost. Здесь нашлось решение как не терять куки - [тыц](https://progi.pro/apache-22-virtualnie-hosti-prilozheniya-tomcat-7-10748980).

Но мне оно например не совсем подошло, ибо на сервере ещё крутятся сайты на php, и всё конфигурируется автоматически wep панелью из шаблонов. Сделать можно, но есть шанс что-то сломать.

Нашёлся более элегантный и простой способ - установка пути вручную. В моём случае, привязан домен и доступ к index файлу осуществляется из корня (site.com/index.html), по сему просто добавляем в web.xml:

```
  <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
```